# jquery - How do I scrollTop animate to the next visibile div/class depending on my scroll position?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Pardon me if the title is a bit vague, cause I wasn't sure how to write it down.

basically:

We have a page with 6 'scenes'. They all have the class `.scene` and a different ID, for example: `scene1`, `scene2` etc...

at first, we had to dynamically change the color for each scene -> scene 1 is a light color, and the last scene is black. That works so far, even while adding or removing scenes.

There is a `<li>` on the top and bottom of the page.  Which has a clickable `<a>` tag.

When I press `nextButton`, I need to go to the next visibile scene **depending on my position on the page**. So if I scroll to scene 2, and I press the button, I need to go to scene 3. If I scroll to scene 5 and press the button, I need to go to scene 6, etcetera... Same counts for the other button `previousButton`, but the other way around (upwards).

Also, if i reach the end of the page with `nextButton` (scene 6), it will go back up to scene 1. All done using `scrollTop`

I have been googling around in regards to this, but i cannot seem to figure out what to do exactly or how to start.

the whole piece of code that is written undere `$(window).scroll(function)` 'till the `each()` function has been given to us by the tutor.

```js
var brightness = 90 ;
var $totalScenes = $('.scenes').length;


$('.scenes').each(function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color" : "hsl(99, 100%, "+  brightness + "%"   + ")" });

    //je hebt 6 scenes en je wilt weten hoe groot de stappen zijn. vanaf de min bereken je hoe groot de stap is. dit doe je 1x (100/totalScenes - 1), dus van 100 naar nul in 5 stappen is 20. Dit herhaalt zich telkens.
    brightness = brightness - 100/($totalScenes - 1);

    console.log(brightness);

});


$(window).scroll(function() {
    // is in viewport function
    $.fn.isInViewport = function () {
        var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
        var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

        return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    };


    $('.scenes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            console.log("dit is " + this.id);

            if(index >= $totalScenes / 2) {
                $('li').css({"color": "#fff"});
            }
                else {
                     $('li').css({"color": "#000"});
                }
            }
    });

});


$('#nextButton').click(function()  {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).closest('.scenes').next().offset().top });     
//          scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().find('.scenes').offset().top } , 100);
});
CSS
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.scenes {
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw; 
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10vh;
    line-height: 100vh;
}

.circle{     
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}


li {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em; 
    position: absolute;
}

li a{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;

}

#previous {
    top: 20px;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#next {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <?php include 'template-parts/head.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

<header>

    <ul>
        <li id="previous"><a id="previousButton" href="#">prev &#8593;</a></li>
        <li id="next"><a id="nextButton" href="#">next &#8595;</a></li>
    </ul>

</header>  

<main>

    <div id="wrapper">    
        <div id="scene1" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">1</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene2" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">2</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene3" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">3</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene4" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">4</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene5" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">5</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene6" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">6</span></h2>
        </div>    

    </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
var brightness = 90;
var $totalScenes = $(".scenes").length;
var nextElment = "scene1";
$(".scenes").each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background-color": "hsl(99, 100%, " + brightness + "%" + ")"
  });

  //je hebt 6 scenes en je wilt weten hoe groot de stappen zijn. vanaf de min bereken je hoe groot de stap is. dit doe je 1x (100/totalScenes - 1), dus van 100 naar nul in 5 stappen is 20. Dit herhaalt zich telkens.
  brightness = brightness - 100 / ($totalScenes - 1);

  console.log(brightness);
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  // is in viewport function
  $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

  $(".scenes").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      console.log("dit is " + this.id);
      nextElment = this.id;
      if (index >= $totalScenes / 2) {
        $("li").css({ color: "#fff" });
      } else {
        $("li").css({ color: "#000" });
      }
    }
  });
});

$("#nextButton").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + nextElment)
      .next()
      .offset().top
  });
  //          scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().find('.scenes').offset().top } , 100);
});

$("#previousButton").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + nextElment)
      .prev()
      .offset().top
  });
  //          scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().find('.scenes').offset().top } , 100);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for reaching out. A few questions:

1. so far press "next" or "previous" only works once. how can i  make sure i can keep pressing it?
2. How cna I make sure the scroll-position of mine is also taken in account? like i said in my post: If i scroll myself to scene 2, I press next, i need to go to scene 3 (or scene 2 if previous). Or if i scroll to scene 5, "next" should bring me to scene 6  and "previous" to scene 4 etc.

Comment: I took a closer look to your code, and I noticed that it started to work when you added the `nextElment = this.id;` to the `$(".scenes").each()` function.

I at first just copy-pasted the `$("nextButton").click()`  and the var you made.

Could you tell me what the `var elment = "scene1";` and `nextElment = this.id;` do?

Comment: Also, I noticed that when I click `next` on scene 6, i go to scene 1, which is good! but if i try to do it the other way (scene 1 to scene 6) it doesnt seem to work. Any idea how to fix that? :)