# Easiest way to make my click-to-scroll function loop infinitely? (scrollTop / Animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is somewhat a similair question compared [to a question I had before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329915/jquery-how-do-i-scrolltop-animate-to-the-next-visibile-div-class-depending-on) but I got a few steps done.

We have a page with 6 'scenes'. They all have the class `.scene`.

When I press `nextButton`, I go to the next visibile scene depending on my position on the page. So if I scroll to scene 2, and I press the button, I need to go to scene 3. etc...

I managed to figure out where i went wrong in regards to assigning `.animate()` and `scrollTop` property, and managed to get the `previousButton` and `nextButton` to work no issue. At this point I can go to the next or previous div, with the requirement that I needed.

It has to work dynamically like this, for if more or less `divs` will be added.

Now i need to make sure that it scrolls "endlessly". If I am at the **last** scene, and I press `nextButton`, i will scroll back to the top, and continue it's regular function. if I am at the **first** scene and I press `previousButton`, I scroll down to the last scene/div. So no matter how much i click, it keeps going in a continuous loop

What's the easiest way to get this done? so far if I reach either end, I get an error that says that it "`cannot read property 'TOP' of undefined`"

**JQUERY**

```
var brightness = 90 ;
var $totalScenes = $('.scenes').length;

 // is in viewport function
    $.fn.isInViewport = function () {
        var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
        var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

        return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    };



$('.scenes').each(function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color" : "hsl(99, 100%, "+  brightness + "%"   + ")" });

    //je hebt 6 scenes en je wilt weten hoe groot de stappen zijn. vanaf de min bereken je hoe groot de stap is. dit doe je 1x (100/totalScenes - 1), dus van 100 naar nul in 5 stappen is 20. Dit herhaalt zich telkens.
    brightness = brightness - 100/($totalScenes - 1);

    console.log(brightness);

});


$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {

    $('.scenes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {

            console.log("dit is " + this.id);

            if(index >= $totalScenes / 2) {
                $('li').css({"color": "#fff"});
            }
                else {
                     $('li').css({"color": "#000"});
                }
            }
    });

});


$("#nextButton").on('click', function() {

     $('.scenes').each(function() {
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            nextSlide = $(this).next();
        }
    });

     $("html, body").animate ({scrollTop: $(nextSlide).offset().top});
});



$("#previousButton").on('click', function(index) {

     $('.scenes').each(function() {
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            prevSlide = $(this).prev();
        }
    });

        $("html, body").animate ({scrollTop: $(prevSlide).offset().top});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <?php include 'template-parts/head.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

<header>

    <ul>
        <li id="previous"><a id="previousButton" href="#">prev &#8593;</a></li>
        <li id="next"><a id="nextButton" href="#">next &#8595;</a></li>
    </ul>

</header>  

<main>

    <div id="wrapper">    
        <div id="scene1" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">1</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene2" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">2</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene3" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">3</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene4" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">4</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene5" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">5</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="scene6" class="scenes">
            <h2><span class="circle">6</span></h2>
        </div>    

    </div>

</main>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.scenes {
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw; 
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10vh;
    line-height: 100vh;
}

.circle{     
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}


li {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em; 
    position: absolute;
}

li a{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;

}

#previous {
    top: 20px;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#next {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem has to do with this (and the related section for previous):

```js
nextSlide = $(this).next();
```

In this situation, `.next()` would return an empty collection if `this` were the last of its siblings. Later, `.offset()` returns `undefined` when supplied with this empty group. The error is generated when trying to access `.top` on that resulting `undefined`.

To fix this, you'd need to ensure that you handle the possibility that `nextSlide` could be empty. There are several ways to do this. One such solution might be:

```js
// your existing code
$('.scenes').each(function() {
  if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
    nextSlide = $(this).next();
  }
});

// additional code to fix the issue
if(nextSlide.length == 0) {
  nextSlide = $('.scenes').first();
}

// back to your existing code
$("html, body").animate ({scrollTop: $(nextSlide).offset().top});
```

Comment: nevermind my previous comment(deleted). Thank you!

may i ask, how would it go for the other way around? so for `previousButton` to loop to the bottom of the page when reaching the top (scene 1)?

Comment: [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) is the counterpart for [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/).

Comment: Alright. Will the IF-statement be the same? I changed `nextSlide` to `prevSlide.length`, but that doesnt seem to work out, or i made a small mistake

Comment: It should, assuming you made all the matching changes to the `#prevButton` click handler. `nextSlide` to `prevSlide` and `first()` to `last()`.

Comment: hmmm weirdly enough it doesnt seem to work. It works fine in codepen (except for the `#prevButton`) but in brackets it doesnt seem to work, and it doesnt fire up an error either

Edit: wait a minute, is my `.offset().top` code not meant to be in an "else" ? i just removed the `else` and now it works